# Ipython requires pymzq but already installed

Tags: jupyter-notebook, importerror, pyzmq

I am trying to install ipython notebook on my mac OS 10.8.5 but it is telling me that I don't have pyzmq but I have already installed that using sudo pip install, and when I pip freeze, pyzmq is there. I have pyzmq version 14.

How can I fix this problem so that ipython will run in my browser?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 563, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 381, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 406, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 40, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('2.1.11', 'IPython.html')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 37, in check_for_zmq
    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11
```

Comment: Are you trying to install iPython inside virtualenv?

Comment: I initially just tried to install ipython on the main user but because it wasn't working, I installed virtualenv to create a new environment and then tried to install ipython again.

Comment: If you install inside virtualenv, it will through an error. It is better to install outside the virtualenv

Comment: even outside of the virtualenv it gives the same error